# Issue surrounding stacked subplots in dash stacking on top of one another

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

in the graph below, I am trying to plot three plots, a candlestick plot, a line scatter plot, and another line scatter plot. The problem is that the second subplot (orange line - proof it is there in legend), is being overrun by the third subplot.

I have tried toggling with height/width, row heights, etc, all to no avail. This graph is being produced in dash, and the code for the graphing section is below. Thanks for the help!

[image]

```
                fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1, shared_xaxes=False, shared_yaxes=False)
                fig.add_trace(go.Candlestick(name="Candlesticks", x=spx_data["date"], open=spx_data["open"], high=spx_data["high"], low=spx_data["low"],
                                         close=spx_data["close"], text=spx_data["date"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), row=1, col=1,)
                fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=squeeze_data["date"], y=squeeze_data["su"], mode="lines", name="SU",
                                         line=dict(color="green")), row=1, col=1,)
                fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=squeeze_data["date"], y=squeeze_data["mid"], mode="lines", name="MID",
                                         line=dict(color="black")), row=1, col=1,)
                fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=squeeze_data["date"], y=squeeze_data["mo"], mode="lines", name="MO",
                                         line=dict(color="red")), row=1, col=1,)
                fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=squeeze_data["date"], y=squeeze_data["npd"], mode="lines", name="NPD"), row=2, col=1,)
                fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=squeeze_data["date"], y=squeeze_data["vex"], mode="lines", name="VEX"), row=3, col=1,)
                fig.update_layout(height=1000, xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False, yaxis=dict(domain=[0.25, 1]), yaxis2=dict(domain=[0, 0.25]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coming from the code snip:

```
yaxis=dict(domain=[0.25, 1]), yaxis2=dict(domain=[0, 0.25])
```

Once removed the graph was corrected.